# How can I pass the state from one component to another and how can I modify the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have

one component called section.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import SectTitle from './Section_Title/Section_Title.js'
import SectContent from './Section_Content/Section_Content.js'

import classes from './Section.module.css'

const section = (props) => {
    const sectionNameMapping = {
        profile: 'Profile',
        education: 'Education',
        relevantWorkExp: 'Relevant Work Experience',
        otherWorkExp: 'Other Work Experience'
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.Section}>
            <SectTitle title={sectionNameMapping[props.sectionName]} />
            <SectContent sectionName={props.sectionName}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default section;
```

SectionTitle.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

import classes from './Section_Title.module.css'

import expandArrow from '../../../assets/png_files/expand_arrow.png'

class SectTitle extends Component {
    state = {
        arrowClicked: false
    }

    displaySectionContents = () => {
        console.log('[displaySectionContents] Executed ... ' + this.state.arrowClicked)
        this.setState({
            arrowClicked: !this.state.arrowClicked
        })
    }

    render(){
    return (
        <div className={classes.SectionTitle}>
            <div>{this.props.title}</div>
            <div>
                <button
                 className={classes.ButtonSectTitle} 
                 onClick={this.displaySectionContents}>
                     <img className={classes.ExpandArrow} 
                      src={expandArrow} 
                      style={{transform: this.state.arrowClicked ? 'rotate(0deg)' : 'rotate(-90deg)'}}/></button></div>
           </div>
    )}
}

export default SectTitle;
```

SectionContent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import SectionItem from './Section_Item/Section_Item.js'

import classes from './Section_Content.module.css'

class SectionContent extends Component {   
    render() {
        return (
        <div className={classes.SectionContent}>
            <SectionItem sectionName={this.props.sectionName}/>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SectionContent;
```

and SectionItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import classes from './Section_Item.module.css';

import jsonContent from '../../../../assets/json_files/json_content.json';


class SectionItem extends Component {
    render() {
        if (Object.keys(jsonContent).includes(this.props.sectionName) && (this.props.sectionName == 'profile')) {
            return <div>{jsonContent[this.props.sectionName]}</div>
        } else {
            return <div>test</div>
        }
    }
}

export default SectionItem;
```

I need to set the state in the sectionTitle where my expand arrow is and the section content be displayed or not based on whether the button has been pressed or not.

I am new to react and I don't know how o do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a simple tree like that you better move your `arrowClicked` and the handler to parent `Section` (turn it to a class based component). you then pass down as props `displaySectionContents` to `SecTitle`. since state is at parent tree you can conditional render `Content` based on `arrowClicked` state:

```
class Section extends Component {

    state = {
        arrowClicked: false
    }

    displaySectionContents = () => {
        console.log('[displaySectionContents] Executed ... ' + this.state.arrowClicked)
        this.setState({
            arrowClicked: !this.state.arrowClicked
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.Section}>
            // pass down the arrow handler and arrowClicked
            <SectTitle title={sectionNameMapping[this.props.sectionName]} displaySectionContents={this.displaySectionContents} arrowClicked={this.props.arrowClicked}  />
             // if arrow clicked is true SectContent is rendered
            { this.state.arrowClicked && <SectContent sectionName={this.props.sectionName}/> } 
        </div>
    )
}
```

SectTitle becomes a function component since it doesnt need state, and you use only passed down props:

```
const SectTitle = (props) {
    return (
        <div className={classes.SectionTitle}>
            <div>{props.title}</div>
            <div>
                <button
                 className={classes.ButtonSectTitle} 
                 onClick={props.displaySectionContents}>
                     <img className={classes.ExpandArrow} 
                      src={expandArrow} 
                      style={{transform: props.arrowClicked ? 'rotate(0deg)' : 'rotate(-90deg)'}}/></button></div>
           </div>
    )}
}
```

once you click on button `props.displaySectionContents` will update parent state, and `SectionContent` will have access to `arrowClicked` to be evaluated properly

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions.

The easiest one is to add some state to `section` component and getters/setters to children

```js
const section = (props) => {
 const [arrowClicked, setArrowClicked] = useState(false)

 return (
        <div className={classes.Section}>
            <SectTitle displaySectionContents={() => setArrowClicked(true)} title={sectionNameMapping[props.sectionName]} />
            <SectContent arrowClicked={arrowClicked} sectionName={props.sectionName}/>
        </div>
    )

class SectTitle extends Component {
    state = {
        arrowClicked: false
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.SectionTitle}>
            <div>{this.props.title}</div>
            <div>
                <button
                 className={classes.ButtonSectTitle} 
                 onClick={this.props.displaySectionContents}>
                     <img className={classes.ExpandArrow} 
                      src={expandArrow} 
                      style={{transform: this.state.arrowClicked ? 'rotate(0deg)' : 'rotate(-90deg)'}}/></button></div>
           </div>
    )}

class SectionContent extends Component {   
    render() {
        // this.props.arrowClicked
        return (
        <div className={classes.SectionContent}>
            <SectionItem sectionName={this.props.sectionName}/>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Another one could be `React.Context`, use another state management framework like, `Redux`, `MobX`... <strike>or just store state in window object, and trigger `forceUpdate()`, no don't do that</strike>